# Python PermissionError: [Errno 13]

Tags: python

Why I cant exctract zip files? I am runing pycharm as Admin..

```
z = zipfile.ZipFile(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\Hist_b3",'r')

z.extractall(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\Hist_b3")
```

Returns:

```
   z = zipfile.ZipFile(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\Hist_b3",'r')
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\zipfile.py", line 1182, in __init__
        self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Users\User\Documents\Hist_b3" can't be both the zip file and the output directory. You have to open the actual zipfile, not a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
test = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\User\Documents\Hist_b3")

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".zip"):
        z = zipfile.ZipFile(path+"//"+item, 'r')
        z.extractall(path)
```